# Who are The Dwarves of the Pink Galley?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

> The dwarves of The Pink Galley now know a few facts about eagle training.

This message appeared after the Dwarven caravan (from The Rim of Perplexing) had left. Just before, I had trained an eagle from wild to semi-wild. Who are the dwarves of The Pink Galley, and who told them about my eagle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dwarf Fortress is a [procedurally generated game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_generation#Video_games). This means that every time you make a world, an entirely new, never-before-seen continent/history/civilization/etc. is created.<sup>1</sup>

The Dwarves of The Pink Galley are dwarves who, in your world, happen to live in some place that got the name "The Pink Galley." There's really no more to it than that. There's no Dwarf Fortress canon or official backstory wiki, etc. You can load your world in the [Legends](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Legends) mode, where you may be able to discern some of the history of whatever place happens to be called The Pink Galley.

As mentioned in the comments, the message you're seeing is one about your own settlement. **Congratulations, The Pink Galley is you, and you know how to train eagles!**

---

<sup>1 - You can '[seed](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/v0.31:Advanced_world_generation)' the world generator in order to reproduce a previous world, but this is the exception, not the norm.</sup>

Comment: The caravan was not from TPG, which is why I wrote their name in my post. Just recently, I got the same message but about ibex training, without any prior caravan or liaison.

Comment: There's no TPG in the civilisation list, but I'll check Legends mode.

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that The Pink Galley is actually my own settlement...

Comment: @Anna The message is one I'm not familiar with, and is probably relatively new. All of the above still stands, though. And if indeed TPG is *not* your settlement, the information most likely disseminates via caravans, though possibly at differing rates.

Comment: @DanRasmussen it is a new message coming from the animal training update a few months ago

Comment: @Anna: It is your settlement.

Comment: @Daenyth: Seems like my settlement is called "Brushurn". According to Legends, The Pink Galley seems to (it's a bit unclear) be the 7-dwarf expedition that founded Brushurn.

Comment: @Anna: There's 3 names: Your civilization, your expedition group, and your settlement.